# Brand new to coding in python and coding in general

Tags: python

I am tinkering with some code online and stumbled upon this one :

```
import os
import time
#Must Access this to continue.
def main():
    while True:
        UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
        PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")

        if UserName == 'Bob' and PassWord == 'rainbow123':
            time.sleep(1)
            print ("Login successful!")
            logged()

        else:
            print ("Password did not match!")

def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("Welcome to ----")

main()
```

I am trying to make it so after the username and password has been implemented, that this sequence happens next:

```
def mainname():
    while True:
        Firstname = input("Enter First Name:")
        Lastname = input("Enter Last Name:")

        if Firstname == 'Cher, Madonna':
            time.sleep(2)
            print("May I have your autograph, please?")

        else:
            print("that's a nice name")
mainname()
```

But what happens is, after I put in the username and password it then loops back to inputting the username and password. How do I make it so after the username and password has been implemented, then it goes to the first name and last name sequence? Thank you very much for the help

Comment: It loops back because there is an endless `while` loop. If you don't need it to repeat, maybe delete the loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

The code that checks the password is in a `while True:` loop, so it will keep looping and asking for the password regardless.

You want to break out of the loop on success, so add a `break` after you successfully log in.

Comment: Also that `if Firstname == 'Cher, Madonna':` line doesn't do what I think you want it to do.

Comment: Because it wasn't part of the question. I'm just *commenting* on unrelated things, so I use comments.

Answer (score 0):

Right after you have confirmed that the password is correct just add break. This will end the while loop as the correct username and password is entered.